# Use route53 domain as alias for an noip ddns domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, noip

I want to have instead of example.ddns.net example.com as my domain.
I've registered my domain at Amazon AWS
My question: How can I setup that it does this.

I tried to make an CNAME record and entered as Value my ddns.net domain.
But it shows following error.

RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name example.com. is not permitted at apex in zone example.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can never use a CNAME at the apex of a zone, e.g. for example.com.  You can only use it for hosts in the zone, such as www.example.com.

Options:

*(Simple)*

Use www.example.com. Create the CNAME. This will work as expected.  You can then use an empty S3 bucket named example.com (the bucket name must be exactly the same as your domain name) along with an Alias record, to create a redirect to www.example.com, [described here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3/).

*(Really simple)*

Use www.example.com as the CNAME, as above, and then create an A record with the IP address shown at the top of [this page](http://wwwizer.com).  This of course is a third party dependency, so, do your due diligence. (I am not affiliated with this company.)

*(More complex, but guaranteed to impress your friends)*

Create a CloudFront web distribution.  Use example.com as the Alternate Domain Name¹ and use the ddns hostname as the Origin Host.  Then, in Route 53, create example.com as an A record, set Alias to Yes, and select or type the dxxxexample.cloudfront.net hostname that was assigned to your domain when you created it.  Wait until the distribution status in the CloudFront console shows "Deployed."  Surf to your site at example.com.

You'll be paying for CloudFront in this scenario, of course, so be sure to familiarize yourself with that.

---

¹ *Alternate Domain Name.*  The CloudFront documentation also refers to this field as a CNAME.  Disregard that.  It is apparently a case of an unfortunate dumbing-down of the documentation, presumably because the term CNAME is so often casually used in name-based virtual hosting, so they called it what people expect it to be called.  Sometimes this value will correspond to a CNAME record, but obviously not this time.

Comment: Is AWS limiting the aliases to Amazon owned properties? I'm getting "The record set could not be saved because: - Alias Target contains an invalid value." I'm about to set an alias to xxxx.sn.mynetname.net.

Comment: @barbazoo alias record targets can only be (a) other records in the same Route 53 hosted zone or (b) records exposed by certain AWS services, like S3, ELB, CloudFront, and Elastic Beanstalk.  They are *internal* lookups, done entirely inside Route 53. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html